# For loop executing only once

Tags: c

I am trying to create a function that prints the string on the console by directly writing to the stdout stream instead of using printf. But the problem is that the for loop only executes once. What is the reason of this ?

Here's the code:

```
int print_string(const char *string, const int buffer_size)
{
    int i = 0;
    char curr = '\0';
    for(i = 0; i < buffer_size; i++) {

        printf("([%d] buffer_size: %d) ", i, buffer_size);
        printf("%c\n", string[i]);

        curr = ungetc(string[i], stdout);

        if(curr != string[i]) { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while writing string to stdout.\n");
        return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

PS: the printf calls are just for debugging purposes.

When I call `print_string("test", 4);` I get the following output: `([0] buffer_size: 4) t`

Thank you.

Comment: What is the return value of `print_string("test", 4)`?

Comment: `ungetc` is for *input* streams. `stdout` is an *output* stream.

Comment: Is there any evidence that the program ended because it blew up on the ungetc(), rather than properly exiting the loop and function? I agree with @EricFinn that the ungetc() is wrong. Fix that (what are you trying to do? You may be limited to one character pushed back.) and see what happens.

Comment: @PhilPerry I guess writing to the wrong stream was the problem... I fixed it by fwriting to stdout. Thanks :)

Comment: @Drake You can answer your own question and mark it as accepted.

Comment: why are you assigning `i` twice? If you assign it in the for loop, no need to initialize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to write to `stdout` stream but I was doing so using `ungetc()` which is meant for input streams. This resulted in a crash. To fix this, I wrote to `stdout` using `fwrite((string+i), sizeof(char), 1, stdout);`